# Map Mouse Buttons using hidutil, how to find Keycodes?

Tags: keyboard, mouse, keybindings

I am trying to map the two side buttons of my Logitech Anywhere MX 3 to volume increment/decrement *without* using any additional tools, ideally using `hidutil`.

My idea was to generate a plist for launch, like done [here](https://hidutil-generator.netlify.app).

Karabiner-Elements is able to map without problems:
[image: Screenshot of Karabiner-Elements Preferences window]

I'd been able to identify the correct device for the hidutil matching:

```
Devices:
VendorID ProductID LocationID UsagePage Usage RegistryID  Transport            Class                      Product                                      UserClass                                       Built-In 
0x46d    0xb025    0xaa3c803e 1         2     0x100000c18 Bluetooth Low Energy IOHIDResource              MX Anywhere 3                                (null)                                          (null)
```

Now I am trying to **find the correct key codes** for Button 4 and Button 5 and Volume Decrement and Increment for several days.

Is anybody aware of them?

Apple only lists keyboard key codes in their [Technotes](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2450/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40017618-CH1-KEY_TABLE_USAGES).

Cross-Post also on [Github](https://github.com/pqrs-org/Karabiner-Elements/issues/2795).

P.S.: Initially I wanted to map the middle button below the wheel, too but this button does not generate any events. I know there is a way to adjust the firmware for Logitech mice (here MX Revolution) to change the wheel's behavior, but that would require a rewrite for macOS. (See the Ensourced article "[Linux, MX Revolution and the Middle mouse button](https://ensourced.wordpress.com/2011/10/24/linux-mx-revolution-and-the-middle-mouse-button/)")

Comment: The MX series are well-known for not transmitting regular key codes. You usually have to use Logitech Options.

Comment: @Tetsujin I know, but Button 4 and 5 send common key codes, observable without Logitech Options e.g. using Karabiner-Elements Viewer. That's why I want to map these, not others. Unfortunately Karabiner / Better Touch Tool etc do not show the raw values of those codes.

Comment: Have you tried [Key Codes](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/key-codes/id414568915?mt=12) (freeware) - I had a look but I'm seeing what Options is mapping to so can't test without disabling & reboot.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thank you for the suggestion. Yes, tried it, but it is only able to show keyboard key codes, not even a left button click of the mouse :/ I also tried to find a header file with them but had no success.

Comment: There was a lot of blog posting around the interwebz about this stuff from the 3rd party mouse driver guys [USB Overdrive, SteerMouse etc] when these first came out. After a decade or more of using SteerMouse [for 'regular' multi-button mice], I had to eventually give up & use Options, because nothing else could intercept it properly. [You can't even get them to work in tandem like with other proprietary drivers, it ends up being either/or.] I have to admit I gave up the fight a couple of years ago & haven't re-investigated since.

Comment: @Tetsujin Right, but I really want to avoid the bloat of it. Mapping a regular button should be possible, Karabiner can map it as BetterTouchTool, too. Just the middle button below the wheel is "Logitech Options Only", as it does not send any regular events.

Comment: Wish you luck but I can't really investigate further. I've tried periodically with newer versions of SteerMouse over the past few years - totally uninstalling Options - to eventually have to swap back again because SteerMouse just cannot handle the buttons 'properly', in a way I'd actually want it to. I was great on my previous MX-518 :\

Comment: @Tetsujin No problem, thank you very much for your help and the suggestions. Yes, this is a pitty, but I am already halfway through now. The keycodes of volume increment/decrement are listed here: https://github.com/amarsyla/hidutil-key-remapping-generator/blob/master/src/helpers/keys.js (`0xC000000EA` and `0xC000000E9`). Now I'm "just" searching for the missing Mouse Button Key Codes. Going to dig into the USB manuals.

Comment: Looks like I am wrong. Mice do not send regular scan codes as keyboards :/

Comment: See https://gist.github.com/MightyPork/6da26e382a7ad91b5496ee55fdc73db2

Answer (score 1):

Not possible with `hidutil`, but I wrote a small Daemon with very low resource consumption doing this:
https://github.com/winkelsdorf/MouseEnhancer